# Align buttons vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this card here [image] i want my buttons to show separately and vertically aligned too and also pulled right. How can i achieve that? Her eis the demo card [image]

Here is my code

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <div class="body">
     <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <div class="card main-content">
        <div class="body">
         <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <img id="studentimg" name="studentimg" alt="User Pic" src="/assets/images/student-avatar.png" align="left" width="150" height="150">
                <p>{{studentDetail.firstName}}&nbsp;{{studentDetail.lastName}}</p>
                <span class="pull-right" style="display: inline-block">
                    <button href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" (click)="editStudent(studentDetail.studentKey)"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</button>
                    <button href="#" class="btn btn-danger pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete</button>
                </span>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

```
</div>
```

Comment: You used the class `row` in your snippet, you can use it again

Comment: Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: Where is the CSS?

Comment: [A simple search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Align+buttons+vertically)

Comment: @rob the buttons aren't aligned like the ones in demo above in the link you provided

Comment: @Paulie_D css is generic and the classes are mixed together so i don't think that i should put it here but its simple bootstrap that i am using

Comment: Which version of bootstrap?

Comment: @Paulie_D 3.3.7

Comment: There are 973 same questions in my link. Which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noticed, you added link to `bootstrap 3`, and in this case I can offer something like [this](https://codepen.io/Areeorder/pen/KxgevR)

Answer (score 1):

I can offer you something like this:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <img id="studentimg" name="studentimg" alt="User Pic" src="/assets/images/student-avatar.png" align="left" width="150" height="150">
            <p>{{studentDetail.firstName}}&nbsp;{{studentDetail.lastName}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 buttons-alignment">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editStudent(studentDetail.studentKey)"> 
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And use the styling like this:

```
   .buttons-alignment {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }
```

It's possible to do something better that you need, but it need to know more details about you task.

Comment: Actually this is right solutions. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: you are welcome :)
And it's need to say, that it's decision in case if it used `bootstrap 4`.

Comment: @ahsan In case you'd choose to switch to bootsrat4 you may use the built-in class to achieve your layout : ex https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxaKPB ;)

Answer (score -2):

1- button doesn´t have the attribute href, change to a href

2- button doesn´t need to be pulled right if they are in a span that is floated right... buttons must be in display:block inside that span not floated